# Sexual activities After Marriage

Tags: nikah, husband-wife, masturbation, wife, sexuality

Assalamu Alaikum Everyone, I want to know that after Marriage, Can wife touch husbands penis and rub it to ejaculate sperm? Is it Halal? Is it kind of Masturbation?

Comment: DId you search the site for similar questions? This certainly has an answer somewhere, please check the site before asking question duoplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do it

If it's done by your hands or vice versa to you by your husband

No problem in it